# Importing several lines in a txt file to a single case in R

Tags: r, import

I'm starting to analyze mikrotik devices on a network, an i'm importing the syslog files of mikrotik in R. Files containing structures like this:

```
0 interface=wlan1 radio-name="sxt lite5 ac" mac-address=00:00:0:00:00:00 <br/>
   ap=yes wds=no bridge=yes rx-rate="6Mbps" tx-rate="650Mbps-80MHz/2S/SGI" <br/>
   packets=58695184,53538818 bytes=55932455008,43520313383 <br/>
   frames=58695184,53597189 frame-bytes=55580326648,43203281541 <br/>
   hw-frames=67938053,79500145 hw-frame-bytes=68934458568,47557410755 <br/>
   tx-frames-timed-out=0 uptime=6h9m23s last-activity=0ms <br/>
   signal-strength=-61dBm@6Mbps signal-to-noise=45dB <br/>
   signal-strength-ch0=-64dBm signal-strength-ch1=-63dBm <br/>
   tx-signal-strength-ch0=-61dBm tx-signal-strength-ch1=-63dBm <br/>
   strength-at-rates=-61dBm@6Mbps 0ms,-61dBm@9Mbps 6h9m23s30ms,-60dBm@12Mbps <br/>
                  6h9m23s30ms,-60dBm@18Mbps 6h9m22s830ms,-62dBm@24Mbps <br/>
                  6h9m22s700ms,-61dBm@36Mbps 1h57m17s620ms,-66dBm@48Mbps <br/>
                  35m12s160ms,-61dBm@54Mbps 3h30m12s820ms <br/>
   tx-signal-strength=-59dBm tx-ccq=85% rx-ccq=86% p-throughput=541371 <br/>
   nstreme=yes nstreme-plus=yes framing-mode=none routeros-version="6.45.3" <br/>
   last-ip=192.168.31.62 802.1x-port-enabled=yes authentication-type=wpa2-psk <br/>
   encryption=aes-ccm group-encryption=aes-ccm management-protection=no <br/>
   compression=no wmm-enabled=yes <br/>
   tx-rate-set="OFDM:6-54 BW:1x-4x SGI:1x-4x HT:0-15 VHTMCS:SS1=0-9,SS2=0-9" <br/>
```

I'm stucked because this data is imported in several rows (cases) of a tibble. ¿how can I merge or import all lines to one case (row) of a tibble?

Comment: What function are you using to import the text? Have you tried `readLines()`?

Comment: Alternatively, in order to combine all rows into one character string, you can extract the variable as vector (e.g. something like `syslog <- my_df$syslog`) and then use `str_c(syslog, collapse = "")`

Comment: I don't think you'll find an inbuilt function to parse this format, unless someone has written a package specifically for mikrotic. Your best option is to write your own function to parse this. Import the file as a single string, split it based on the delimiter for each record, and grab the text on either side of the `=` with regex.

Comment: I appreciate your kindly help. 

It works!. I'm begginer in R and your help has useful!!

I was looking before to know if anything about mikrotik was developed, that is the reason I'm looking the best strategies to collect information for a lot of routers, hoping data show me important knowledgment to have best decisions.